# Remove default styles on ConvertKit form in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, forms, plugins, widget

One has a ConvertKit form, that was added using [ConvertKit plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/convertkit/), and uploaded on a widget as follows

[image]

After applying some styles, when I am logged in, the form looks like this

[image]

However, when I log out, there are some default styles being loaded and the form ends up looking like this

[image]

How does one remove ConvertKit default stylings?

There may be different ways of removing the default styles applied by ConvertKit. I have tried the following, but with no success:

Inspecting the form in the front-end, one sees that inside a form with the class `"seva-form formkit-form"`, apart from two `div`, one has a `style` element., as follows

```
<form class="seva-form formkit-form">
   <div class="formkit-background">...</div>
   <div data-style="minimal">...</div>
   <style>...</style>
```

As I have seen that removing the style block `<div data-style="minimal">...</div>` solves the issue with the form, tried, as per [@m4n0's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66488990/remove-html-style-block-on-convertkit-form-in-wordpress?noredirect=1#comment117557300_66488990) applying `.formkit-form div[data=style="minimal"] { display: none; }`, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: `.formkit-form div[data=style="minimal"] { display: none; }` should work.

Comment: @m4n0 it doesn't work. I already added some custom CSS and when I am logged in to the [website](https://goncaloperes.com) I see the form [like this](https://imgur.com/r6OGCiZ). When I am logged out, as you can also see by accessing the website I hyperlinked before, I see it [like this](https://imgur.com/t7wyaSo)

Comment: @m4n0 my goal is to remove the default styles that ConvertKit places on the form and apply a specific one that I have created and that I can see when I am logged in. For that, removing the block `<div data-style="minimal">...</div>` will solve the issue, that is why I asked for a way to do that. There may be other ways to remove the default styles though.

Comment: If you want to remove the wrapper, you can do that using JS.

Comment: Do you want to show it like this? https://nimb.ws/P1YjR9

Comment: @m4n0 yes. The alignment (which I want centered) I will change in the styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your changing requirements that we discussed through comments:

```
form.formkit-form[data-uid="3624b8b144"] {
   border: transparent;
   margin: 0 auto; /* To center the form, you can also use flexbox centering */
}

/* I had to increase the specificity of the below selector because there are other selectors acting on it */

form.formkit-form div.formkit-powered-by-convertkit-container a.formkit-powered-by-convertkit {
   display: none; /* To hide the copyright but check how their licensing works */
}

.formkit-guarantee a {
    color: #fff; /* To change the color of privacy link */
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: It works just great - thank you! I am going to even reward you with a bounty to show my appreciation.
I was using [this](https://jsfiddle.net/goncaloperes/Ldq07jtx) to change the styles, but anytime I was logging out the changes were not taking effect.

Comment: That's so kind of you. The JSfiddle code that you posted is not recommended. The selectors can change when you are working with WordPress. It will work only when you are logged in because it has "logged-in" https://nimb.ws/PHXby8 class attached to it. It also brings in so many conditions that it would work only when you are editing and not when you refresh the page.

Comment: Didn't even realize that and thank you for helping me fine tune future procedures. Next time when considering changing the CSS I will open the website in private mode and copy the CSS Path from the Console that way, as I wont be logged in.